# How to setup "Contens Set" in NSArrayController for Core Data with a one-to-many relationship?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data, nsarraycontroller, nsset

I try to get Core Data working with a simple one-to-many relationship in Xcode.
My 2 entities, employee and department, are setup in the data model, and relationships are created:
  Employee has a to-one relationship to department
  Department has a to-many relationship to employee.

My xib has 2 table views for each entity. I wan to maintain my data there, selecting a department should show all employees, and I can add one more by using the insert method of that controller.
My controllers ( one for each entity) have set:

- entity name
- flag prepares content is set
- Managed Object context is bound to my object context
- reference binding to table view content is set to arranged objects

Now, I thought the idea is to set the "Content Set" in the array controllers to manage the relationships. Like so:
Department.selection.employee  ( for employee )
Employee.selection.department  ( for Department )

But all I get is a BAD ACCESS crash..

Any idea of what is wrong is welcome !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use any of the content bindings of the departments array controller to show all departments. Bind the content set of the employees array controller to `Department.selection.employees`. `Department` is the department array controller, `employees` is the to-many relationship.

Comment: Yes, this was it. No dump anymore. I can enter data in department and employees .  However, I must be missing something else. When I change the selection in department , no employees are shown under the "employess" tableview. How do I sent the selection in department to employees ...

Comment: Did you bind Selection Indexes of the table view to selecionIndexes of the array controller?

Comment: Perfect ! It works now. I can select a department , and the assigned employees are displayed immediately. I can also create an new department and add employess. Thank you very much !